# PHP Code Igniter Encryption doesn't return anything

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, encryption, decode

when i load my controller i have this:

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');

$get = null;
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$get);
$email = $this->encrypt->decode($get["acc"]); // e.g.  www.lol.com/?acc=troll
```

And my controller is called like this:

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$this->load->helper("url");
$user = $this->input->post('email', true);

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($user);
redirect('account/viewaccount?acc='.$encrypted_string);
```

The url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/account/viewaccount?acc=+fgSAs6X7ysW6XDjFVw//9RGVbY751zZv1LQ44yYBjhVuzI1BC1t9BbZCIUdX5lpYA==
```

But the problem is, when i encode i get a value, but then later on, when i decode this huge value (I can receive this value flawless, by testing) it returns nothing, just NULL.

Why is this happening?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoded form is not url safe, try using some other encoding technique or `urlencode` the output of `encode`.

Comment: I don't know why, but when i used your urlencode on the encoded value, and then urldecode on the decoded value of the encoded, it worked :/

Comment: The output of `$this->encrypt->encode($user);` has special characters like `//`, which breaks the url and you don't receive complete encoded value.

Answer (score 3):

The output of the encryption is not URL safe. Replace this:

```
redirect('account/viewaccount?acc='.$encrypted_string);
```

With

```
redirect('account/viewaccount?acc='.urlencode($encrypted_string));
```

And then `urldecode()` it on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

try encrypting a string and decrypt it.
the error may not be the decryption or encryption

Comment: ahh so try to put it in a session or a cookie. beacause you can find an code error, and you can (if you want access the string) at any page